# Android - Different Ids for the same include Layout

Tags: android

I have a layout which I have to Include several times. It consists of a `TextView` and an `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back2"
    android:id="@+id/id_1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/id_2"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Now I want to set the text programmatically, but the problem that I'm facing is, that the `TextView` now always has the same Id, because I'm including the same Layout several times. Is there a way to programmatically include a Layout and always change the Id for each included layout?

Comment: why you are not adding TextView dynamically ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I'd do is, when you need to access the views on a particular instance of the included layout:

```
ViewGroup instance = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.included1); // Replace ViewGroup with whatever your particlar type is
ImageView iView = (ImageView) instance.findViewById(R.id.id_1);
TextView tView = (TextView) instance.findViewById(R.id.id_2);
```

Comment: That's how I usually do it with included layouts.  I have several different generic button setups (two vertical, two horizontal, etc) that I use over and over and reference them based upon the layout they are included in to set different text and actions.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your TextView  dynamically and then use `TextView.setId(int id)` to set the id of that View so that you can call it later with the new id.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do this. You'll have to create the layout w/o using `<include>` if you want the ids in your XML layout to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

For each textview

Change the id in the line `android:id="@+id/id_2"`  to a different id.

For example:

`android:id="@+id/id_4"`

To add them programmatically you can do this:

```
            TextView Label3 = new TextView(this);
            Label3.setId(300);
            Label3.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
            Label3.setLayoutParams(labelParams);
            Label3.setText("My textViewCaption:");
            ll3.addView(Label3);
```

and if you set Label3 as a global variable, you can access it to change it, via `setText`

Programmatically you can loop through this and set the Ids while you loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to change your TextView id
`TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setId(int id);`